# Pointer address changes during extern function call

Tags: c++, c, pointers, cuda, extern

I am writing a program where a C++ file calls an extern "C" function in order to launch several CUDA kernel functions.  While debugging the code, I discovered that the target address for one of my pointers changes when I enter the extern function.

Here is the offending code (within my .cpp file):

```
cout << "knnIndices before launch: " << knnIndices_d << endl;

launch_kernel(numParticles, dptr /*positions_d*/, velocities_d, embedded_d, 
    forces_d, 
  #ifndef USE_ATOMIC_FLOAT
    externalForces_d, 
  #endif
    masses_d, knnIndices_d, dt);

cout << "knnIndices after launch complete: " << knnIndices_d << endl;
```

and within the .cu file:

```
extern "C" void launch_kernel(int numParticles, float4* positions, float4* velocities,
    float4* embedded, float4* forces,
#ifndef USE_ATOMIC_FLOAT
    int4* externalForces,
#endif
    float* masses, int* knnIndices, float dt)
{
    std::cout << "knnIndices at launch start: " <<  knnIndices << std::endl;
```

The output from this is:

```
knnIndices before launch: 0x200420000
knnIndices at launch start: 0x200321400
knnIndices after launch complete: 0x200420000
```

I've run out of ideas trying to explain this behavior, and I would appreciate some help.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that `USE_ATOMIC_FLOAT` is defined differently in the two places? If so, what the caller thinks is `knnIndices` will be what `launch_kernel` thinks is `masses`, etc. Try making your diagnostic `cout <<` report the value of `USE_ATOMIC_FLOAT` and some more of the pointer values, and let us know what you get.

Comment: It might help to declare any variables you don't want or expect to change as `const`. The compiler will then give errors if you are accidentally modifying them. You might also want to try running in valgrind to make sure there is no out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: @smocking thanks, I had thought of that.  Thank you to everyone who responded so quickly with such great suggestions.  I haven't had much experience before this communicating between C and C++, but this has taught me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you defined `USE_ATOMIC_FLOAT` only in one of the sources. So the real index  of the parameter is  wrong, try printing the parameters that are before and after (or just check the code) to confirm.

This is one side of C functions, usually if they are in different object files, the symbol contains only the name of the function, and not the parameters...

Comment: I only pasted a small piece of the full files, USE_ATOMIC_FLOAT is actually set as a compiler argument.  I would think that if it wasn't being defined for one file or the other, there would be linking error before reaching this point... but I will double check just to be sure.

Comment: @skylz : If one source file had it and the other didn't, that would be an ODR violation, which does _not_ require a diagnostic.

Comment: @skylz - glad it worked. This is a very annoying bug (from my experience)

Comment: Wow, you were right on, and you found that so quickly too!  Thanks a bunch, I've been working on this off and on for a week.   It turns out that -DUSE_ATOMIC_FLOAT was being set in my cmake file for CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS, but since compiling the cpp file gets delegated to a different compiler, it wasn't defined for that file.